# defining custom dtype for numpy in cython

Tags: numpy, cython, dtype

I was looking that Sklean's Cython [source code for decision tree](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx), and I found the following custom numpy dtype (on lines 71-85)

```
# Repeat struct definition for numpy
NODE_DTYPE = np.dtype({
    'names': ['left_child', 'right_child', 'feature', 'threshold', 'impurity',
              'n_node_samples', 'weighted_n_node_samples'],
    'formats': [np.intp, np.intp, np.intp, np.float64, np.float64, np.intp,
                np.float64],
    'offsets': [
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).left_child,
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).right_child,
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).feature,
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).threshold,
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).impurity,
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).n_node_samples,
        <Py_ssize_t> &(<Node*> NULL).weighted_n_node_samples
    ]
})
```

I wasn't able to find a definition of `Node` used in the `'offsets'` part of the above code anywhere in the Sklearn documentation, but Sklearn codebase uses `Node` instead of `NODE_DTYPE` everywhere it needs to use this structure.

In particular, I wasn't even able to find any documentation in Cython that explains how the creation of this structure works.

Can someone help me with understanding this? i.e., in particular, does the above Cython code for `NODE_DTYPE` automatically creates a `Node` numpy dtype (without needing to separately declare a `Node` numpy dtype?

Comment: What about the pxd-file which is automatically cimported , I.e. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/tree/_tree.pxd#L25?

Comment: awesome. thanks, i never looked at the pxd file. much appreciated.